# How to get value of the below following

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have to do some validation on focusout using jQuery. My issue is that I cannot take the id from the text area field since it is inside `ng-repeat`.

Can anyone kindly help me to take the id of the particular field inside the ng-repeat to do the validation?

Note: I need to achieve this using jQuery instead of adding directives.

```html
<div class="md-dialog-content;padding: 10px;" ng-repeat="data in inputFields">
  {{data.id}}
  <textarea ng-model="data.inputField" id="inputField{{$index}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter Input Stream Here"></textarea>
</div>
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#inputStream").focusout({
    alert("focusout")
  })
})
```

Comment: '*I need to achieve this using jQuery instead of adding directives*' that's an odd requirement considering you're using Angular - you shouldn't be using jQuery at all in that case.

Comment: yes i know, but i just wanted to achieve this using jquery..kindly help me

Answer (score -1):

You can use wildcard selector:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("[id^=inputField]").focusout({
    alert("focusout")
  })
})
```